# get courses from moodle

Tags: python, moodle

I am trying to write an application that grabs courses from a Moodle system.
There are two different versions of Moodle: 1.9 and 2.5.

How can my application do this? I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: Do you have access to the sql database?  or are you scraping the info?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to SQL database for now. But I'd like to know all the ways how to retrieve the content. It would be a simple parsing or access via web service (but only for version 2.5 as I understand). But I don't know how to do this exactly.

Comment: Hello I am finding the library or the script in python using I can create courses and all that option inside moodle 2.6 release version. do you have any sample script so I can use that for my demo purpose.

Answer (score 0):

What do you need to do with the course?

You can backup a course. This is a single zip file - extension .mbz - that has a bunch of XML files that are parsed by Moodle to restore the course regardless of the database.

http://docs.moodle.org/25/en/Course_backup

You could backup the courses and then parse the xml with Python.

Or if you want to distribute the courses across several Moodle sites than you can create a private community hub.

http://docs.moodle.org/25/en/Hub_administration

Comment: I have to write an application that allow students to see course description they enrolled and see their grades, progress, etc

Comment: You can do that in Moodle though?

Comment: Yes, but some information must be seen from our outstanding system.

Comment: You probably want to use web services - I haven't worked with this before so can't offer any advice. Best of luck. http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Category:Web_Services

Comment: Hello @Russell England, I am finding the library or the script in python using I can create courses and all that option inside moodle 2.6 release version. do you have any sample script so I can use that for my demo purpose.

Answer (score -1):

you can choose the moodle studying with the version of 2.6, it  has good and leatest feature. Try learn from this blog

http://www.squidoo.com/moodle-cloud-hosting-and-the-features-of-version-2-6